# Is eggnog just a milkshake?

Tags: language, dairy, beverages, classification, seasonal

Last year I tried eggnog for the first time, following a homemade recipe involving egg, cream and sugar. The result tasted like a thin vanilla ice-cream milkshake (with spices and alcohol).
Recipes for homemade ice-cream use similar ingredients (without spices and alcohol).

Is this just superficial, or do the definitions of ice-cream milkshake and eggnog overlap so that it is reasonable to conceive of eggnog as a flavoured milkshake?

(I am looking for a technical answer that rules out my milkshake theory, or suggests it's an acceptable substitute.)

Comment: Milkshake is flavoured milk. There is no milk in eggnog that you could say is the base you enrich with flavour. There is Lait de poule where the milk is used.

Comment: Definitely not. I don't think I have enough to add a full answer in terms of knowledge and explanation but I do want to add a minor antecdote. There are  eggnog milkshakes! Which are quite possibly the superior form of both beverages. They use eggnog ice cream, or just some other ice cream and then instead of milk, use eggnog as the thinner. No alcohol in them, but still soooooo goooooooood.

Comment: Grocery store eggnog doesn't seem to contain alcohol.

Comment: @Joshua In many states, grocery stores can't sell liquor.  That's likely why you don't see this in the US (I never have.)

Comment: Mine does, but it's still impossible to get drunk on eggnog.

Comment: @Joshua The grocery stores in my area (Maine) sell eggnog with alcohol or without. The ones without alcohol are located in the dairy section and are typically refrigerated, whereas the ones with alcohol are located in the liquor section at room temperature and have a significant alcohol content. All that being said, I'm not sure how that in any way impacts the quality of the question.

Answer (score 23):

Not really.

For a start there's no milk in it (there's cream, but *milk* is the defining factor in a milkshake). Second, egg isn't a normal ingredient in a milkshake, and neither is alcohol. Of course they can be added, but they take you away from what's normally meant by the term. When that happens it's normally reflected in the name.

In general, trying to precisely categorise foods is an exercise in futility - defining a category that includes everything you'd expect it to invariably includes things that don't belong, or you end up with categories so broad as to be useless. 
[Is a hot dog a sandwich?](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/jul/03/is-a-hot-dog-a-sandwich-nature-america)

Even calling eggnog a cocktail ([*An alcoholic drink consisting of a spirit or spirits mixed with other ingredients, such as fruit juice or cream.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cocktail)) is slightly problematic, as "cocktail" *usually implies* it's mixed just before serving, rather than bottled in between (as is common with eggnog).

Comment: According to the cube rule, hotdog is technically a taco :) http://cuberule.com/

Comment: I use cream in my milkshake every time.

Comment: @Luciano So.... pizza is toast in Naples, a quiche in Chicago, and a taco in New York... that sheds so much light on the pizza wars.

Comment: @bruglesco you're probably not alone.  Even more people probably use sugar (in some form, such as syrup) every time.  Neither cream nor sugar defines it, milk does, hence the name

Comment: Must I've never seen eggnog premixed with alcohol.  That is mixed in later.  Probably this is due to liquor laws in different (US) states.  In may states you can only buy liquor at specially sanctioned stores.  I could see this in states where liquor can be bought in grocery stores though.

Comment: I would think it's the ice-cream that is the key ingredient that defines a milkshake.  You can't just shake up some milk and call it a milkshake.  I'm not sure that the name of things is the best evidence of it's contents.  Head-cheese is not cheese, for example.

Comment: @JimmyJames it's not eggnog until the alcohol is mixed in, it's mix for eggnog. Eggnog is, according to every dictionary and recipe I've seen, an alcoholic drink, and you presumably wouldn't drink the mix. But licencing laws can lead to strange products. As for ice cream defining milkshake - maybe where you are. Here as milkshake with ice cream used to be a luxury milkshake, and you can still buy "milkshake powders" (thickener and flavouring basically) intended to be added to just milk

Comment: @ChrisH: I pour and drink eggnog from the carton. My family thinks milkshake powders are for camping when you can't add ice cream.

Comment: Another [Is it a hotdog or a sandwich](http://existentialcomics.com/comic/268) illustration.

Comment: A milkshake never contains egg _directly_, but the _ice cream_ in a milkshake might. (Of course that leads into other debates about different styles of ice cream, and the difference between ice cream and frozen custard...)

Comment: @ChrisH I believe you but typically when you get a carton of "Egg Nog" in places I've lived, there's no alcohol in it.  Perhaps a liquor store could carry it (not sure) but it's not really in their wheelhouse to carry things that expire like that.  That's my guess.  I think people like to pick their poison, too.  Liquor laws vary greatly from state to state and they often don't make much sense.

Comment: @JimmyJames you may be on to something there.  All recipes I've seen include alcohol, and most dictionary definitions, which the notable exceptions being American.

Comment: Cube rule is awesome.  A sushi is actually not a sushi, but a toast... In no situation is a sushi actually a sushi...!

Comment: @JimmyJames "I would think it's the ice-cream that is the key ingredient that defines a milkshake." I can honestly say that I've never had a milkshake that used ice cream as an ingredient, I think that's a cultural thing.

Comment: @Nelson Typically "sushi" is an uncountable noun.

Comment: @Pharap Just as "rice" is, naturally.

Comment: @Pharap Yeah, I've been thoroughly corrected on this.  Must be regional.  Go for Custard-based if you try one.

Comment: @ChrisH I've actually encountered three different varieties of "eggnog" in my region of the US. There is alcoholic eggnog containing whiskey, brandy or other spirits. There is a very heavy, undrinkably thick non-alcoholic concoction intended, as you say to be mixed (and thinned) with the alcohol of your choosing. Finally, there is moderately thick non-alcholic eggnog intended to be consumed as sold, which would be a bit too thin if mixed with alcohol. The third is the by far the most commonly seen commercially around here.

Answer (score 9):

Egg nog is a custard. The only difference is you don't freeze it in an ice cream mixer. It has all the same ingredients as ice cream except a heavier use of alcohol.

I haven't tried but I'd bet you could freeze it, too.

Comment: Egg nog ice cream is excellent IMO, better tasting than the drink to me.  The spices come through better and if you like the adult hit, a smaller amount of alcohol seems to impart a smoother flavor without affecting the freezing.

Comment: That depends on your definition of *custard*! Many say it hasd to be cooked to be custard, while others permit freezing as well. Eggnog can be raw.

Comment: Cooked eggnog- like what you buy in the grocery store and what I make at home- is a custard. Traditional eggnog is basically just eggs and bourbon/rum and is not a custard at all.

Comment: @ChrisH I've never come across a definition of custard that referenced freezing at all... Is this one of those US/UK language things, like how in the US 'sherbet' is apparently a frozen thing rather than a powder.

Comment: @Sobachatina I decided to make egg nog for the first time in years just a couple of days ago. I looked at two saved recipes titled "Traditional Egg Nog". Both use eggs, bourbon and rum, sugar and cream and milk. So do the others I've seen. Of those two, one is from Bon Appetit and the other is from Cook's Illustrated.

Comment: @Spagirl neither had I until searching earlier today, but [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/custard)  says "baked, boiled, or frozen".

Comment: Would most agree that egg nog is a custard base or at least a custard-like base as an accurate description?  To me an unset custard base regardless of if a cooked or uncooked egg nog seems accurate.  You are basically going through the custard motions without gelling it or at least only slightly.

Comment: @Rob- sure. But they traditionally aren't cooked and that's a requirement for being called a custard- not just containing eggs and milk. Sorry if I was ambiguous by abbreviating the ingredient list.

Comment: @spagirl- In the US, 'Custard' != 'Ice Cream' except among people who only know the word "Custard" in the context of "Frozen Custard" sold at some fast food places. There are several types of Ice Cream and a custard base is only one of them. That said- custard style eggnog does make a fabulous base for custard style ice cream.

Comment: Go into a supermarket this time of year in the southeastern U.S. (maybe other parts of the country too, I don't know), and you can usually find jugs or cartons of "boiled custard". It is very similar to eggnog, and sold as an alternative to eggnog...but I don't think anyone I know could explain what the difference actually _is_.

Answer (score 9):

For one thing, eggnog (around in one form or another for hundreds of years) significantly predates milkshakes. Even switching the order of invention, though, still no :)

A milkshake is based on ice cream and milk, blended with flavoring. Some variants don't include ice cream, but a milkshake is always thick and cold. It doesn't include any eggs. You could have an eggnog *flavored* milkshake by adding spices and alcohol, but it wouldn't be eggnog.

Eggnog must include eggs, with cream and milk added to make it richer and thicker. Traditionally it is alcoholic (and milkshakes traditionally are not). While not served hot, it is never as cold a drink as a milkshake.

Comment: Where do you find milkshakes that don't contain ice-cream?  I've never seen such a thing.  I thought you have ice cream in order to call it a milkshake in the US and that's why it's a 'shake' at McDonald's or a 'frosty' at Wendy's.

Comment: @JimmyJames the sticking point on the fast food versions would be the milk, not the ice cream.  Even milk could be stretched to be made with cream as that is still milk fat.  But once you go non-dairy, then you have cross over and using milk-shake is false.

Comment: @dlb I found [this](https://eatsiptrip.10best.com/2018/04/19/why-you-cant-order-a-milkshake-at-mcdonalds/) which says it's state by state.  Bizarrely in Mass. you can't even have cream or ice-cream in a 'milkshake'.  Where I grew up we'd get milkshakes made with frozen custard which isn't too far off of eggnog.

Comment: Yeah, the whole "frappe" thing in Massachusetts is still weird to me :)

Comment: @Erica I was just totally wrong so carry on.

Comment: Interesting bit from the "Milkshake" article on Wikipedia: _When the term "milkshake" was first used in print in 1885, milkshakes were an alcoholic whiskey drink...described as a "sturdy, healthful **eggnog** type of drink, with eggs, whiskey, etc., served as a tonic as well as a treat"._ (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to stand by my answer as "current usage" but clearly history says something different.

Comment: My mom used to make home-made milk shakes in the blender without ice cream using milk, ice and vanilla. They were pretty damn good from what I remember.

Answer (score 2):

The similarity is not superficial in that the ingredients and preparation of eggnog is essentially the same as those for making a custard style ice cream.   In effect, drinking eggnog is drinking unfrozen custard style ice cream base, with some liquor thrown in.

The difference is in the subsequent preparation: a milkshake involves blending ice cream and milk and flavorings into a frozen thick drinkable concoction while eggnog is traditionally served warm.

Is eggnog a milkshake? No the final product is too different.  Is the similarity superficial? Again no, the ingredients and initial preparation are essentially the same (though the proportions will differ).

Answer (score -1):

No. Eggnog  is more a thin custard (especially the lightly cooked versions, the raw egg recipes less so)

Comment: Disagree with the review comment.  There are better answers here, but it *is* an answer.

Answer (score -2):

A milkshake is made from *milk*, while eggnog is made from *cream*. If an eggnog has milk, it is technically a form of milkshake. However, this would be stretching the definition of milkshake. The same applies to the cocktail argument.